# Webpack resolve extension "Module not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

*Warning:* I'm pretty new to webpack, please be gentle

Okay so I'm trying to set up webpack, and I got everything working fine with es2015 and imports with webpack. I'm running into an issue where now I'm trying to add the extensions to `resolve` so that I don't have to declare the file extension, but it always says that it can't find the file or module. Any idea why this could be? Here's my `index.jsx` and my `webpack.config.js`

```
// index.jsx
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import App from './components/App'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore.js'

const store = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Here's the `webpack.config`:

```
// webpack.config
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/javascripts/index.jsx'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/public/'
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __DEV__: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders: [ 'react-hot', 'babel-loader' ],
        include: path.join(__dirname, '/src')
            },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      }
        ],

        preLoaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' }
        ],

    resolve: {
      root: [
        path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'stylesheets')),
        path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'javascripts'))
      ],
      alias: {
        '@style': path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'stylesheets')),
        '@script': path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'javascripts'))
      },
      extensions: [
        '',
        '.webpack.js',
        '.web.js',
        '.jsx',
        '.js',
        '.scss'
      ]
    }
    }
};
```

As I said, if I change line 5 in `index.jsx` from `import App from './components/App'` to `import App from './components/App.jsx'`, it works and I have no idea why. Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like your `resolve` is inside module

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that lol, wanna add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `module` is wrapping around your `resolve`, which is ruining the config file. If the `resolve` isn't there then Webpack can't resolve your extension, forcing you to add the extension. You should always indent uniformly to keep track of and prevent these types of errors.

---

When you import it without an extension, Webpack doesn't know how to resolve the extension so it can't correctly load it. You have to specify `.jsx` so then Babel comes in and imports it as a `.jsx` explicitly.

Comment: Is that not [what resolve extensions](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) is for?

Comment: Thanks man! The first part is definitely what was wrong. Probably have been staring at this for too long lol